# Aircrack monitor mode disconnects other dongle from Wifi

Tags: networking, wifi

I have a setup with a Raspberry Pi with two wifi dongles -- one is the Canakit Ralink 5370 dongle that supports monitor mode, and the other is an Edimax EW-7811Un adapter.

iwconfig:

wlan0 : Ralink dongle

wlan1 : Edimax dongle

When I turn on my Pi with both dongles plugged in, wifi works okay off of wlan1. However, when I run:

```
$ sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

monitor mode is started successfully on mon0, but wlan1 is kicked off of Wifi. That's kind of annoying, but tolerable if I could reconnect, but for some reason I can't reconnect after being kicked off by airmon-ng. This is the error I get:

```
$ sudo ifup wlan1
wpa_supplicant: wpa_action is managing ifup/ifdown state of wlan1
wpa_supplicant: execute `ifdown --force wlan1' to stop wpa_action
run-parts: /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant exited with return code 1
Failed to bring up wlan1.
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Because you are using wpa-supplicant .. which always causes headaches. Try disabling it then do it again.